# Failure to Bind to a Remote IP Address for Akka Actor System

Tags: scala, network-programming, playframework, akka, remote-actors

I was having trouble with initializing an actor system on a remote IP address. I am using akka actors and the play! framework. The code and the remote actor system are both on the remote rackspace servers. When I try to create a remote actor system on the the other server it fails to bind to that IP address. I don't think it is a network or firewall issue because Rackspace says that they opened up all connections between servers. This is the error message I am getting:

```
[error] application - 

! Internal server error, for request [POST /payment/] ->

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at     Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(routes_routing.scala:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(routes_routing.scala:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$3.call(Router.scala:1080) ~[play_2.9.1-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at play.core.Router$Routes$class.invokeHandler(Router.scala:1255) ~[play_2.9.1-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at Routes$.invokeHandler(routes_routing.scala:14) ~[classes/:na]
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(routes_routing.scala:44) ~[classes/:na]

Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /172.17.100.232:2554
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:298) ~[netty-3.3.0.Final.jar:na]
    at akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteServer.start(Server.scala:53) ~[akka-remote-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport.start(NettyRemoteSupport.scala:73) ~[akka-remote-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.init(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:95) ~[akka-remote-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:568) ~[akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:575) ~[akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]

Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:126) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:59) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.bind(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:140) ~[netty-3.3.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleServerSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:92) ~[netty-3.3.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:66) ~[netty-3.3.0.Final.jar:na]
```

I am creating the remote actor system here:

```
object Payment extends Controller {
  var goodies: AuthNetActorObject = null

  val system = ActorSystem("RemoteCreation", ConfigFactory.load.getConfig("remotecreation"))
  val myActor = system.actorOf(Props[authNetActor.AuthNetActorMain], name = "remoteActor")
  ...
}
```

Here is where i define remotecreation in my Application.conf file:

```
remotecreation{ #user defined name for the configuration
    include "common"
    akka {
            actor{
                    #serializer{
                    #       proto = "akka.serialization.ProtobufSerializer"
                    #       daemon-create = "akka.serialization.DaemonMsgCreateSerializer"
                    #}

                    #serialization-bindings{
                    #       "com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage" = proto
                    #       "akka.remote.DaemonMsgCreate" = daemon-create
                    #}

                    deployment{
                            /remoteActor{   #Specifically has to be the name of the remote actor
                                    remote="akka://RemoteCreation@172.17.100.232:2554"
                            #       router = "round-robin"
                            #       nr-of-instances = 10
                            #       target {
                            #               nodes = ["akka://RemoteCreation@172.17.100.232:2554", "akka://RemoteCreation@172.17.100.224:2554"]
                            #       }
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Here is my common.conf file that I include in the definition:

```
akka {

  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }

  remote {
        transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
        log-received-messages = on
        log-sent-messages = on
        log-remote-lifecycle-events = on

    netty {
      hostname = "172.17.100.232"       #Broadcast IP address of remote system
      port = 2554
        log-received-messages = on
        log-sent-messages = on
          log-remote-lifecycle-events = on

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably means that something else is using that port on that machine.   Log into that machine and run `netstat -anp | grep 2554` as root and see that port is in `LISTEN` status.  If so the process ID will be in the last column.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I ssh'ed into the remote machine, became the super user and entered that command. Nothing was returned. And when I did it without the grep i wasn't able to find the port 2554. I also tried netstat -l which lists all listening ports and wasn't able to find it there. Also it seems like something is using all the ports that are listening. I'll try switching to one of them and give you an update. Thanks for your help :).

Comment: Yep it wasn't able to bind. I'll try to find an open one.

Comment: Ok, I just needed to create an application service on the remote ip and port. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/akka-user/-QMuZPQHiF0

Comment: @user687245: Did you find any solution for the problem? I too facing the same issue. I already tried netstat, but it's not returning anything which is bound to the configured port.

Comment: Hi @VaibhavRaj: You have to create a Actor System on those servers. So you have to run the code there and check if there is a service set up and is a listening port for that server. Then will you be able to spawn remote akka actors on that server.